# find point of object in the future given direction and velocity

Tags: trigonometry, physics

I have a point A, and another point B. I know the distance from point A to B. I also know the velocity with which B is moving and its direction. I also know the angle of B with respect to A. I would like to know how to find a future position of B given all the variables known.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates of $B$ at time $t$ are $(x_0+v_xt,y_0+v_yt)$, where $(x_0,y_0)$ is the starting position of $B$ and $(v_x,v_y)$ is the velocity of $B$.  You didn't indicate how you are given the data, so I am not sure if this form fits your need.